# Применить StringFormat ко всем ячейкам DataGrid с определённым типом

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как можно применить `StringFormat` ко всем ячейкам конкретной колонки в `DataGrid` в приложении, которые имеют определённый тип (тип может меняться)?

Например есть таблица как на скриншоте. И пусть подобных таблиц будет несколько в приложении. В таблице есть столбец Money, туда попадают данные с типом decimal. Я хочу сделать общий стиль (или поведение), чтобы в таких колонках (ячейках) контент отображался с форматом, который отделяет десятки, сотни, тысячи. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я это вижу так: использовать либо стили для `DataGridCell`, либо использовать `Behavior`. Начал пробовать Писать стиль с использованием триггера, но не соображу как указать тип данных.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{}">
                
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers> 
    </Style>
```

Колонки могут быть и автогенирируемыми и нет.

Comment: `определённый тип (тип может меняться)?` может меняться, а о каком типе речь и какое форматирование вы хотите к нему применить? Для всех ячеек в таблице или в колонке таблицы? Нужно больше подробностей, отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Колонки таблицы как формируются? Автогенерацией или в XAML прописаны?

Comment: @aepot подправил описание. Второй вопрос: бывает и так и так. Для автогенерации я находил способ через поеведения и подписки на событие AutoGeneratingColumn - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451247

Comment: Для автогенерации надо форматирвоание задавать в свойствах вьюмодели. К примеру `public string MoneyText => Money.ToString("C2");` Для прописанных в XAML колонок можно задать ControlTemplate для каждой колонки.

Comment: Можно еще вот такой фокус сделать https://stackoverflow.com/a/24573388/12888024 с прописыванием стиля для каждой колонки.

Comment: А не знаете ли какой-нибудь вариант со стилями? Например: для всех ячеек, внутри которых контент имеет тип decimal применять вот такой StringFormat?

Comment: Копать Style/Template/DataTemplate(DataType=decimal)/ControlTemplate/разметка